# Matrix as function parameter

Tags: c, parameters

Why when using a matrix as a parameter of a function we must specify the number of columns but we don't have to indicate number of rows?

Comment: Can't say anything for sure without code.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004668/c-allocating-a-matrix-in-a-function/27366086#27366086

Above you will find a program that I have made with functions allocating and manipulating matrices in any possible way for C (gcc C11/C99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a function definition like

```
void foo( int matrix[][COLS] ) { ... }
```

This requires a little background...

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So, given the declaration

```
int arr[10];
```

the *expression* `arr` will have type "10-element array of `int`"; unless this expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `int`".  So if we pass that array to a function, like

```
blurga( arr );
```

what `blurga` receives is a pointer to `int`, not an array of `int`.  So we can define `blurga` as

```
void blurga( int *ap ) 
{ 
  // do something with ap[i]
}
```

The formal parameter `ap` has type "pointer to `int`".  Note that you can use the `[]` operator on pointer expressions as well as array expressions<sup>1</sup>.

Now, in the context of a formal parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.  So we can rewrite that function definition as

```
void blurga( int ap[] )
{
  // do something with ap[i]
}
```

Again, `int ap[]` is interpreted exactly the same as `int *ap`.

Now let's look at a two-dimensional array:

```
int blah[10][10];
```

The expression `blah` has type "10-element array of 10-element array of `int`".  Going by the conversion rule above, the expression `blah` will decay to an expression of type "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[10]`.  So if we pass `blah` to a function, what the function receives is a pointer to an array, not an array of arrays:

```
void bletch( int (*barr)[10] );
```

As before `T a[]` is interpreted as `T *a`, so we can write that declaration as

```
void blech( int barr[][10] ); // barr[] == (*bar)
```

Just remember that `barr` is a *pointer* type, not an array type.

---

<sup>1. In fact, `a[i]` is defined as the result of `*(a + i)`; given a pointer value `a`, we offset `i` *elements* from that address and dereference the result.  So basically, the conversion rule still applies; the array expression `a` is being converted to a pointer expression, and that pointer expression is what the `[]` is being applied to.</sup>