# Passing a two dimensional array to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define column 3
#define row 3
#define share 3

int matrix_multiplication(int left_matrix[][column], int right_matrix[][column], int result_matrix[][column], int rows, int cols, int shared);

int A[][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
},
B[][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
}, C[3][3]; //initialize "hard coded" three matrices

int main() {
    matrix_multiplication(A, B, C, row, column, share); //passes address of each matrix to function
    return 0;
}

int matrix_multiplication(int left_matrix[][column], int right_matrix[][column], int result_matrix[][column], int rows, int cols, int shared) {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//stays within first column and row through first iteration
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)//ensures inner dimensions match with variable k i.e. ixk * kxj =ixj or A*B=C
                result_matrix[i][j] += right_matrix[i][k] * left_matrix[k][j]; //C programming has ability to perform matrix multiplication
            //Adds result of each operation to C matrix i.e. +=
            printf("%d\t", result_matrix[i][j]); //matrix C is composed of rows(i) and columns(j)
        }//new tab after each column iteration
        printf("\n"); //new line for each row iteration
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is an good example of passing multidimensional arrays to a function using pointers and printing multidimensional arrays after mutliplication. There are multiple ways to indicate pointers to the compiler. I recommend seeing the "Correct way of passing a 2 dimensional array into a function." for example:

```
/*void display(int (*p)[numcols],int numRows,int numCols)//First method//
void dispaly(int *p,int numRows,int numCols) //Second Method//
void dispaly (int p[][numCols],int numRows,int numCols)  //Third Method*/
```

Comment: A two dimensional array is `int**`, not `int*`. What error are you getting on the multiplication line?

Comment: @JasonBaker No, `int **` is not a **2d** array it's an array of pointers.

Comment: You cannot pass 2d arrays through as parameters in c or c++ as a simple `int arr[][]` parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way of passing 2 dimensional array into a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446707/correct-way-of-passing-2-dimensional-array-into-a-function)

Comment: Please post the full original error message, with the file names and line numbers.

Comment: line 24 "expected primary-expression before ']' token"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004668/c-allocating-a-matrix-in-a-function/27366086#27366086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `column` variable, and add this above the `matrix_multiplication` function declaration:

```
#define column 3
```

(You may also want to rename `column` to `COLUMNS`.)

In C++ you can also do this:

```
static const int column = 3;
```

or, in C++11:

```
constexpr int column = 3;
```

The idea behind all this is that all but the very first size of a multidimensional array must be known at compile time.

---

To fix the `expected primary-expression before ']' token"` error, change your inner assignment to something like this:

```
result_matrix[i][j] += right_matrix[i][k] * left_matrix[k][j];
```

---

Also you should initialize `result_matrix` with 0s first.

---

Also remove the `*` from `int *result_matrix[][column]`.

Most modern compilers display warnings if you pass an `int` instead of an `int*`. Please enable all warnings in your compiler, recompile, fix them, and update your question stating that the example code compiles cleanly, without warnings.

---

To print an element of the matrix, you have to specify which element you want to print:

```
printf("%d\t", result_matrix[i][j]);
```

I can't believe that your compiler didn't display a warning when you omitted the `[i][j]`. Warnings are for your benefit: they indicate possible bugs in your code.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following, I have already removed the column variable and replaced it with the directive #define column 3 above the function prototype statement.

Comment: `int* result_matrix[][column]` is also wrong, and `printf("%d\t", result_matrix);` is brave, but doomed to failure.

Comment: It was int* result_matrix[][column]. Can't believe I missed that. The 3X3 prints properly with the new tab printf line but the values are all 4223008 in the 3X3 array.

Comment: I've added a couple of more suggestion to my answers and fixed the indexes (`[i][j]` instead of `[i][k]`) in the `+=' formula.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. This is my first programming class, and this forum has really helped! It was the print statement lacking the desired elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004668/c-allocating-a-matrix-in-a-function/27366086#27366086